# Sorted Dictionary and List<>() has an error in VS 2010

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have a code , i get it from my question from stack overflow

```
# Read data
var data = new SortedDictionary<(string id, string idr, string email), 
    List<(string reference, decimal amount)>>();

using (var input = File.OpenText("input.txt"))
{
    List<(string reference, decimal amount)> currentInvoice = null;

    for (var line = input.ReadLine(); line != null; line = input.ReadLine())
    {
        var fields = line.Split(new char[] { '@' }, 6);
        switch (fields.Length)
        {
            case 2:
                // Sanitize input
                if (fields[0] != "INV")
                {
                    throw new Exception("Unknown record type.");
                }
                if (currentInvoice == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Invoice without context.");
                }

                // Parse
                var invoiceEntry = fields[1].Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 
                    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                if (invoiceEntry.Length == 2)
                {
                    decimal amount;
                    if (decimal.TryParse(invoiceEntry[1],
                        NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands,
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        out amount))
                    {
                        currentInvoice.Add((invoiceEntry[0], amount));
                    }
                }

                break;

            case 6:
                var currentContext = (id: fields[0], idr: fields[2], email: fields[5]);
                if (!data.TryGetValue(currentContext, out currentInvoice))
                {
                    currentInvoice = new List<(string reference, decimal amount)>();
                    data.Add(currentContext, currentInvoice);
                }
                break;

            default:
                throw new Exception("Unknown record.");
        }
    }
}
```

SortedDictionary can't be used it says

> ' using `system.collection.generic.sorteddictionary<TKey,TValue>` requires 2 agruments '

the `List<(string reference, decimal amount)> currentInvoice = null ;`  has an error too , it says

> 'Only assignment,call,increment, decrement, new object expression can be used as a statement'

how to fix this?

Comment: Am i missing something here? there is no error with this code in my environment (though thats not to say there is not other issues)

Comment: @TheGeneral hmm im sure you're not missing something , i dont know why this code error , the SortedDictionary function cannot be used , and i dont know why ..

Comment: The compiler on VS2017 tells me: *Impossible de définir une classe ou un membre qui utilise des tuples, car le type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TupleElementNamesAttribute' nécessaire au compilateur est introuvable. Une référence est-elle manquante ?* => ?

Comment: Is there anyway to fix this? And i cant understand the language sorry

Comment: @Olivier I think in the past you had to include the `System.ValueTuple` package from NuGet.

Comment: I think you are using pre C#7 (maybe)

Comment: @Enrico It says "It's impossible to define a class or member which uses tuples, because the type System.RunTime.CompilerServices.TupleElementNamesAttribute necessary to compile couldn't be found. Are you missing a reference?" - it's not exactly relevant to your situation. You said that you're using Visual Studio 2010, which I thinks limits you to an older version of the .NET Framework (4.0?) which doesn't support value tuples (introduced in 4.7).

Comment: @john Yes, it works. Good to know.

Comment: I think its time to upgrade your visual studio.

Comment: So i cant use this code .. okay thankyou i will find another way to clear my task , thanks for the help 

Comment: @TheGeneral hehe i want too , but Office PC only has this IDE and i think i must work with my laptop to fix this task ..

Comment: You could use a custom class with three string properties instead of the tuple, if that's the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an older version of Visual Studio you **may be able to fix** this by installing the following from *nuget*

- [Microsoft.Net.Compiler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/)
- [System.ValueTuple](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/)

<sub>***Note*** : Take notice of the dependency, you may need to install an older version that supports your targeted framework</sub>

It also should be noted, that if you are using VS 2010, it's time to tell your bosses/managers to upgrade, or use the community version.